# When I call the controller method using ajax call every time parameters of method has same value

Tags: ajax, parameter-passing, call, onchange, dropdown

My View Is as follow:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductColorId, "Select Color", new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label required-field" })
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductColorId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Color, "ProductColorId", "ProductColor"), new { @class = "form-control col-lg-5 ", @id = "ddProductColor" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProductColorId)
    </div>
    <br />
</div><br />
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, "Select Company", new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label required-field" })
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Company, "CompanyId", "CompanyName"), new { @class = "form-control  selectpicker", @id = "ddCompany" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CompanyId)
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to fetch id of selected option of the drop down and wanna send it to the controller method.
My ajax call JS is following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    customerId = 5;

    colorId = $("#ddProductColor option:selected").val();
    companyId = $("#ddCompany option:selected").val();
    initializeProductFile();
});

function initializeProductFile() {
    $form = $('#productfileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        formData: { customerId: customerId, colorId: colorId, companyId: companyId}
    });
    debugger;
    $("[name=jobId]").val(customerId);
    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: '/LooksFile/GetFileList',
        data: { customerId: customerId, colorId: colorId, companyId: companyId},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#productfileupload').fileupload('option', 'done').call($('#productfileupload'), $.Event('done'), { result: { files: data.files } })
            $('#productfileupload').removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }
    });
    $('#productfileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');

}
```

And my controller method looks like following:

```
public JsonResult Upload(int customerId, int? colorId, int companyId)
```

Yous little assist can pleasure me.Thanks in advance.